# quarks connect elasticsearch error Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\httpsTest\OpenSSL\bin

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, quarkus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDvBt.png)
I clone quarkus-quickstarts from github
But when i execute `mvn install` occurs this error

I don't know where can i find the path and remove "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zfwN.png)
here is my directory

version
win11，quarkus : 3.5.1，maven : 3.9.5，elasticsearch cloud : 8.5.3

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/elasticsearch-quickstart

use quarkus connect elasticsearch and catch alerts
when catch a alert , it will send mail to user

Comment: Your path is enclosed in quotes. That should be used when passing it to commands, but not when you create a `Path` from it.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that an error occurred because quarkus.elasticsearch.hosts is not set.
I resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that an error occurred because quarkus.elasticsearch.hosts is not set.
I resolved it.
that " is two ''.after I set quarkus.elasticsearch.hosts,it works

application.properties

```
quarkus.elasticsearch.hosts = your elastic host
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).